# How to access configuration in windows class library project created in Asp.Net Core MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, class-library

I have a new Asp.Net Core MVC website. Asp.Net core only targets full .net 4.6.1 framework.

I have added another project to the solution, which is windows (not Asp.Net core) class library. This class library was developed before 2 years but recently converted to target .net framework 4.6.1. So I thought to re-use it. I was able to bring the reference in with Asp.Net core mvc site. However, I like to inject configuration (IOption) to this class library. I tried searching around but I could not find any help. I find a few posts where there was a discussion around adding a startup.cs in class library and retrieving the configuration. However, it was not quiet clear from the discussion, which type of class library they were discussing about. I think I could implement the same with class libraries build with .NET Core. However, how I can achieve the same implementation with older libraries I have.

I really appreciate any help on this. I like to access IOption service in the class library developed earlier.

Comment: Have you tried reading the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/configuration.html#using-options-and-configuration-objects)?

Comment: Yes. I have set up options service exactly following the same way the documentation talks about in Asp.Net Core MVC project. However, I don't know how to access them in another class library type project. As said earlier this library was developed before 2 years and may not have required dependencies so that IOptions can be injected into. I am wondering whether there is any possibility to reuse this class library without making much refactoring on it. It depends on several configuration and that must be available to work it properly.

Comment: The same way you inject any service: Add `IOption<T>` to your service constructor. When your service is resulved, `IOption<T>` will be resolved too, were `T` is the class where your configuration is stored in

Comment: @Tseng: Thanks for reply. IOption<T> is part of Microsoft.Extensions.Options namespace and can be used by downloading the NuGet package. I am not able to do that in a classical class library. Therefore, I am not able to inject services using constructor. I may be missing something here. Is there any good sample available somewhere where I can have a look at?

Comment: Okay. I think may be able to do it. I was just missing -pre while downloading the package. Now let me try running the entire solution to check whether the implementation is working. Thanks.